# Area of quadrilateral using determinant/cross product

Tags: geometry, determinant, cross-product

Consider a quadrilateral whose sides are given by the vectors $\vec{a}, \vec{b}, \vec{c}$ and $\vec{d}$, such that $\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c}+\vec{d}=0$.

I'm told that the area of the quadrilateral can be calculated by half of the determinant of the matrix with columns given by the diagonals of the quadrilateral.

**Why is this the case?**

My initial approach was to use the cross product to find the area of the parallelogram spanned by two sides of the quadrilateral but this didn't seem yield anything meaningful. 
[image]

Comment: What do you know about the relationship of the determinant to areas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider an arbitrary quadrilateral.

Move two vertices parallelly to a diagonal, so that two sides become aligned with the other diagonal. This transformation does not change the area.

Then move a vertex so that one side becomes aligned with the first diagonal. This transformation also preserves the area.

The area is that of a triangle, half the cross-product of the diagonal vectors.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For parallelograms:

Assuming that $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ are the 2 non-parellal vectors of the parallelogram, then the diagonals of this parallelogram are $\vec a +\vec b$ and $\vec a - \vec b$

Now by applying the cross product you get $||(\vec a +\vec b) × (\vec a -\vec b)||=2||(\vec a ×\vec b)||=2A$

($A=$area of the parallelogram).

For the general case:

Consider the quadrilateral $ABCD$ of center $O$ (the intersection of diagonals) and consider the parallelogram formed by drawing 2 parallel lines to $(AC)$ one passing through $D$ and the other through $B$, and also another 2 parallel lines to $(BD)$ one passing through $A$ and the other through $C$. Let this parallelogram be $A'B'C'D'$ (for example name the vertex that is to the right of $A$ by $A'$ and the vertex right to $B$ by $B'$ and so on).

Now the determinant of the cross product of the diagonals of the quadrilateral gives you the area of this parallelogram ($||\vec {AC} ×\vec {BD}||=||\vec {A'B'} ×\vec {A'D'}||= A_{A'B'C'D'}$), but also you can easily show that the triangles $AA'B$ and $AOB$ are congruent (which means that they have the same area), and also the triangles $BB'C$ and $BOC$ are also congruent and so on, this means that the area of $A'B'C'D'$ is just double the area of the quadrilateral $ABCD$, and this is the result we want.

[image]

$$A_{ABCD}=\frac{A_{A'B'C'D'}}{2}=\frac{||\vec {AC} ×\vec {BD}||}{2}$$

Comment: Thank you for the note, I fixed that

Comment: WOW! Awesome method Fareed!

Answer (score 3):

Consider the plane embeded in 3-diomensional space, so that we can use vector product.

Area of a triangle with sides $\vec{a}$, $\vec{b}$ and $\vec{c}$ ($\vec a+\vec b+\vec c= 0$) is given by $$ S_\triangle = \frac12|\vec a||\vec b|\sin (\angle ab) = \frac12|\vec a \times \vec b|$$
Notice that you can divide the quadriteral into two triangles, one with sides $\vec a, \vec b, \vec c+\vec d$, and the other with sides $\vec a+\vec b, \vec c, \vec d$ ($\vec a+\vec b = -\vec c-\vec d$). We have

$$S_1 = \frac12|(\vec c+ \vec d) \times \vec a| $$
$$ S_2 = \frac12|\vec d \times (\vec a+\vec b)|= \frac12|(\vec c +\vec d) \times \vec d| $$
The total area is 
$$ S = \frac12 |(\vec c+ \vec d) \times (\vec d+\vec a)| $$.
Note that $\vec c+\vec d$ and $\vec d+\vec a$ are the two diagonals, and you have $$ |\vec v\times w| = |{\rm det}[\vec v, \vec w]|$$